# Load all node titles with db_query()

Tags: database

```
$title = db_result(db_query("SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid = %d", 1));
```

with this code i can get title from node with id == 1. But how can i load all node titles with specific content type?

```
$title = db_result(db_query('SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE type = %s', $content_type));
```

Please correct my code to get all node titles from specific content type and how to limit them by 20 items for example?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using? The Drupal 7 syntax is different than Drupal 6 syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$result = db_query_range("SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE type = '%s'", $content_type, 0, 20);
$titles = array();
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $titles[] = $row->title;
}
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/group/database/6

Comment: Thanks, mate. WHat does mean 0 before 20? 0, 20 (20 means - how many items will be shown, but what does mean zero?)

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query_range/6 "$from The first result row to return."

Comment: OK, thanks again. Just one more question :) Is there no options to display nodes which starts on A letter only?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like WHERE title LIKE 'A%%'